# How to display item from array to specific indexPath in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uicollectionview

I need to display collection view in diifferent manner.I have an items array like the following:

```
items = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"]
```

Then I need display my collection view look like the following:

[image]

How to achieve this way of implementation?

I tried to implement the following way:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

                let cell = chartCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ViewCell2", for: indexPath) as! ViewCell2
                cell.lblTitle.text = self.getDataFromArray(index: indexPath.row)
                return cell
   }
```

But this result is now look like the following:

[image]

Comment: You want your data to be randomly placed, right?

Comment: Your array is fixed and static? if yes then why don't you alter your array data :)

Comment: Array is always dynamic,@rv7284,Need place data randomly

Answer (score 1):

You can randomised your data using method `shuffle()` which is mutating func
OR `shuffled()` which returns shuffled element array

`items = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I"].shuffled()`

Complexity: O(n), where n is the length of the collection.

Doc:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994753-shuffle 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994757-shuffled

Comment: But How to display for eg:  item "E" on the first cell on collection view?

Comment: @IKKA Didn't get your point , But after randomised data you can load into datasource and get data with indexPath normally you do with any any array